# Как выбрать значение из массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Потратил уже полдня на эту "ошибку" и никак не могу найти решение, есть массив:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        ["option_id"]=> string(2) "13" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
        ["option_id"]=> string(2) "14" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(1) { 
        ["option_id"]=> string(2) "18" 
    } 
}
```

Он получен при помощи `SELECT` из базы данных, код `SELECT`:

```
$product_option_query = $this->db->query("SELECT `option_id` FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option WHERE product_id = '" . $product_id . "'");
```

Дальше в цикле я прохожу по значениям этого цикла (значения этого цикла находятся в самом начале поста):

```
foreach ($product_option_query->rows as $product_option) {
    $index = $product_option;
    $option_image = $this->db->query("SELECT `option_image` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "option` WHERE `option_id` = '" .  $product_option['option_id'] . "'");
}
```

Но по итогу в массиве `$option_image` находится только значение `SELECT` с первым `option_id`, и последующие значения, соответственно, не записываются. Помогите с этим разобраться или направьте меня в нужно направление, а то никак не могу с этой банальной, на первый взгляд, проблемой разобраться.

Comment: За это надо отрывать руки автору db. И тебе тоже, за то что делаешь еще один запрос вместо того чтобы сразу выбрать все одним запросом с помощью джойна

Comment: Ну руки всегда вырвать можно успеть, если не затруднит, можешь скинуть как будет примерно выглядит мой запрос при помощи джойна?

Comment: Затруднит. Если у тебя проблемы с джойнами, купи учебник и почитай. Впрочем,  никогда нельзя недооценивать глупость собеседника. foreach в примере реальный, ты так и получаешь $option_image и потом пытаешься его где-то использовать?

Comment: Да, я его таким получаю и использую, в чём вопрос?

Comment: а не смущает, что в $option_image  по определению будет только одно значение?

Comment: Эм, хорошо, почему в нём только одно значение будет?

Comment: А СКОЛЬКО ТАМ БУДЕТ, по твоему? если написать $a = 1;$a=2;$a=3; то что будет в $a? 123?

Comment: @Ипатьев вопрос в сторону: в коде же явно описывается словарь, почему он массивом-то называется?

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `".DB_PREFIX."product_option` po  LEFT JOIN `".DB_PREFIX."option` o  ON po.option_id = o.option_id WHERE product_id = '" . $product_id . "'");
```

Comment: Sql inhection. Sql inhection. Sql inhection.

Comment: @Qwertiy инхекция?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, копипаст опечаток работает :)